# Reshape cannot infer the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input sizes are non-zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I looked a a couple of post as this seem to be a very common issue, but none of them worked for me.
I had this working on a windows machine with Tensorflow 1.11 but when I try on a Unbuntu machine with tensoflow 1.10 and updated to 1.13 but it gives me this error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Reshape cannot infer the missing input size for an empty tensor unless all specified input sizes are non-zero
 [[node Flatten_1/flatten/Reshape (defined at /home/matt/GitClone/PythonGitRepo/DNN/SelfDrivingCar/TrafficSignClassification/LeNETExample/Model/LeNet.py:69) ]]
```

I am a bit lost on what the issue is as this should be a simple port over from windows to linux.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the main code for the program:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.utils import shuffle

import tensorflow as tf

from DataScripts import PreprocessData as predata
from Model import LeNet

# TODO: Fill this in based on where you saved the training and testing data

# Data set locations and paths
trainingPath = "TrainingData/train.p"
testingPath = "TrainingData/test.p"

# Get the data from the data sets using pickle to read them in
with open(trainingPath, mode="rb") as training_data:
    train = pickle.load(training_data)

with open(testingPath, mode="rb") as testing_data:
    test = pickle.load(testing_data)

# Create the features and labels for the data and link them
x_train, y_train = train['features'], train['labels']
x_test, y_test = test['features'], test['labels']

print("x_train shape:", x_train.shape)
print("y_train shape:", y_train.shape)
print("x_test shape:", x_test.shape)
print("y_test shape:", y_test.shape)


# Define number of training samples and number of testing samples
num_train = len(x_train)
num_test = len(x_test)
# Define the number of classes (only the unique vales in y sets)
num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))

# Define the image shape and data shape
image_shape = x_train[0].shape
print("Num of Training Samples:{} - Num of Test Sample:{} - Num Of classes:{}".format(num_train, num_test, num_classes))

# histogram of label frequency Simple data exploration
hist, bins = np.histogram(y_train, bins=num_classes)
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
plt.show()


# Process all the data and create validation data

x_train, x_test_normalized, x_validation, y_validation =     predata.preprocessData(x_train, y_train, x_test)


# Build LeNET Model
EPOCHS = 60
BATCH_SIZE = 100
rate = 0.0009 # Learning rate

tf.reset_default_graph()
# Tensor placehoders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32, 1)) # Define shape of a image 32X32
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))              # Class label
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)            # probability to keep     units
one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y, 43)


# Start the training

logits = LeNet.makeModel(x, keep_prob)
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits, labels=one_hot_y)
loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = rate)
training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y, 1))
accuracy_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,     tf.float32))
saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    num_examples = len(x_train)

    print("Training...")
    print()
    for i in range(EPOCHS):
        x_train, y_train = shuffle(x_validation, y_validation)
        for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
        batch_x, batch_y = x_train[offset:end], y_train[offset:end]
            sess.run(training_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.5})

        validation_accuracy = LeNet.evaluate(x_validation, y_validation, BATCH_SIZE, accuracy_operation, keep_prob, x, y)
        print("EPOCH {} ...".format(i + 1))
        print("Validation Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(validation_accuracy))
        print()

    saver.save(sess, '.\lenet')
    print("Model saved")


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    saver2 = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./lenet.meta')
    saver2.restore(sess, "./lenet")
    # Test accuracy on test sets
    test_accuracy = LeNet.evaluate(x_test_normalized, y_test, BATCH_SIZE, accuracy_operation, keep_prob, x, y)
    print("Test Set Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(test_accuracy))
```

And this is the LeNEt method:

```
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow.contrib.layers import flatten

def makeModel(x, keep_prob):
    mu = 0
    sigma = 0.1

    # Layer 1: Convolutional. Input = 32x32x1. Output = 28x28x6.
    W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 1, 6), mean=mu, stddev=sigma), name="W1")
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(6), name="b1")
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b1)
    print("layer 1 shape:", x.get_shape())

    # Activation function.
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    # Max Pooling. Input = 28x28x6. Output = 14x14x6.
    x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')
    layer1 = x

    # Layer 2: Convolutional. Output = 10x10x16.
    W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 6, 16), mean=mu, stddev=sigma), name="W2")
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(16), name="b2")
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b2)

    # Activation function.
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    # Max Pooling. Input = 10x10x16. Output = 5x5x16.
    x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')
    layer2 = x

    # Layer 3: Convolutional. Output = 1x1x400.
    W3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5, 5, 16, 400), mean=mu, stddev=sigma), name="W3")
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W3, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
    b3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(400), name="b3")
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b3)

    # Activation function.
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    layer3 = x

    # Flatten. Input = 5x5x16. Output = 400.
    layer2flat = tf.layers.flatten(layer2)
    print("layer2flat shape:", layer2flat.get_shape())

    # Flatten x. Input = 1x1x400. Output = 400.
    xflat = tf.layers.flatten(x)
    print("xflat shape:", xflat.get_shape())

    # Concat layer2flat and x. Input = 400 + 400. Output = 800
    x = tf.concat([xflat, layer2flat], 1)
    print("x shape:", x.get_shape())

    # Dropout
    x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob)

    # Layer 4: Fully Connected. Input = 800. Output = 43.
    W4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(800, 43), mean=mu, stddev=sigma), name="W4")
    b4 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(43), name="b4")
    logits = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, W4), b4)

    return logits

# x and y are tensorflow place holders
def evaluate(x_validation, y_validation, BATCH_SIZE, accuracy_operation, keep_prob, x, y):
    num_examples = len(x_validation)
    total_accuracy = 0
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_x, batch_y = x_validation[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE], y_validation[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE]
        accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_operation, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y, keep_prob: 1.0})
        total_accuracy += (accuracy * len(batch_x))
    return total_accuracy / num_examples
```

And this is the preprocessing code for the data

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

def preprocessData(x_train, y_train, x_test):
    # Convert to grayscale
    x_train_rgb = x_train
    x_train_gry = np.sum(x_train / 3, axis=3, keepdims=True)

    x_test_rgb = x_test
    x_test_gry = np.sum(x_test / 3, axis=3, keepdims=True)

    print('RGB:', x_train_rgb.shape)
    print('Grayscale:', x_train_gry.shape)

    x_train = x_train_gry
    x_test = x_test_gry

    ## Normalize the train and test datasets to (-1,1)

    x_train_normalized = (x_train - 128) / 128
    x_test_normalized = (x_test - 128) / 128

    ## Shuffle the training dataset and create the validation set
    # Validatioin set will not be used by Training

    x_train_normalized, y_train = shuffle(x_train_normalized, y_train)
    x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(x_train_normalized, y_train,
                                                                    test_size=0.20, random_state=42)

    print("Old X_train size:", len(x_train_normalized))
    print("New X_train size:", len(x_train))
    print("X_validation size:", len(x_validation))
    return x_train, x_test_normalized, x_validation, y_validation
```

The data set can be found here
https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/February/5898cd6f_traffic-signs-data/traffic-signs-data.zip

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Hi Cris, I understand what you mean as this is a lot of code, but I also gave all the code so that anyone can run this program and see along with a download to the data that I am using. Easy to recreate the issue then.

Comment: Easy to recreate the issue, yes, but hard to find the issue because there's lots of code. This makes the debugging job harder. You are the one that should be doing the hard work, it is your project after all. By cutting down the code to a minimum that shows the problem, it will be easier to spot the problem. And you might be able to spot it yourself!